# Como exibir valor relacionado a combobox na textbox?

Tags: c#, sql-server, webforms, ado.net

Estou fazendo um projeto em C# e SQL Server, e necessito que o item selecionado na combo exiba os valores correspondentes em uma `textbox`.

Segue os códigos que já tentei:

```
        private void preencherCBDescricao()
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=FS5;Initial Catalog=bdsi01;User ID=bdsi01;Password=*****");

            try
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException sqle)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Falha ao efetuar a conexão. Erro: " + sqle);
            }
            String scom = "select titulo from Livros";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(scom, con);
            DataTable dtResultado = new DataTable();
            dtResultado.Clear();//o ponto mais importante (limpa a table antes de preenche-la)
            cbocompra.DataSource = null;
            da.Fill(dtResultado);
            cbocompra.DataSource = dtResultado;

            cbocompra.DisplayMember = "titulo";
            cbocompra.SelectedItem = "";
            cbocompra.Refresh(); //faz uma nova busca no BD para preencher os valores da cb de livros.


        }

        private void cbocompra_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string stg;
            stg = cbocompra.SelectedItem.ToString();

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=FS5;Initial Catalog=bdsi01;User ID=bdsi01;Password=*******");

            try
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException sqle)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Falha ao efetuar a conexão. Erro: " + sqle);
            }

            String scom = "select * from Livros where titulo="+ stg;


            txtautor1.Text = cbocompra.SelectedItem.ToString();
            txtedit1.Text = cbocompra.SelectedItem.ToString();
            txtpreco.Text = cbocompra.SelectedItem.ToString();

        }
```

A questão é, como posso guardar os valores do meu select em uma lista e após o item ser selecionado eu usar o valor desse item para procura na lista os dados correspondente como o Nome autor, preço para carregar os meus `textbox` com essas informações ?

Tipo criar uma lista e com ela carregar meu `combobox`, e quando o usuário selecionar um item eu carregar os `textbox` com as informações desse item.

Comment: Qual o comportamento deste código? Exibe erro? Executa, mas os valores não aparecem? Qual seria?

Comment: Qual o seu principal problema nesse código?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, fiz uma edição na pergunta , acredito que seja isso que ela precisava...

Comment: Estou com certa dificuldade para fazer os dados que estão ligados a combobox aparecer na textbox, por exemplo: tenho uma tabela livros no banco de dados e na minha combobox aparece os nomes dos livros cadastrados e eu queria que na textbox aparecesse o autor daquele livro selecionado na combobox

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza O correto seria ela mesma editar, mas aprovando a edição podemos reabrir.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, perfeito

Comment: Quero ajuda para resolver o meu problema, não para editar a minha pergunta. Desculpa se fui grossa, mas nas textbox aparece datareader gridview em vez dos dados solicitados.

Comment: @NataliaSouza, A questão é que não ficou clara sua pergunta, Veja o que vc precisa explica se é que entendi, no primeiro método seu `preencherCBDescricao` vc carregar seu `cbocompra` com o resultado do seu select e no seu método `cbocompra_SelectedIndexChanged` vc esta querendo carregar os seus `TextBox` de acordo com o que vc tem no `cbocompra` para isso vc tem que manter uma lista do select que vc fez no primeiro método ou ir novamente ao banco para buscar essas informações, ... se for isso edite sua pergunta explicando melhor...

Comment: @NataliaSouza, acho que nem sempre nos expressamos da melhor forma, acho que as edições bem intencionadas são bem vindas. Voltando ao seu problema, tudo bem se subir no Git um projeto com a solução completa do seu problema ? As respostas abaixo já foram satisfatórias ?

Answer (score 4):

Este processo é bastante simples.

No vosso exemplo, supondo que a tabela não tem uma chave primária (ID) que identifica os registos de forma unívoca, o controlo **ComboBox** terá que receber a tabela completa para fazer todo o trabalho por si, indexando cada registo (`DataRow`) na sua lista para ser acedido pela propriedade `SelectedItem`.

Ajustando o código:

```
    private void preencherCBDescricao()
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=FS5;Initial Catalog=bdsi01;User ID=bdsi01;Password=*****");

        try
        {           
            String scom = "select * from Livros";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(scom, con);
            DataTable dtResultado = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dtResultado);

            //Limita aos itens da lista pendente
            cbocompra.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            cbocompra.DataSource = null;               
            cbocompra.DataSource = dtResultado;
            cbocompra.DisplayMember = "titulo";
            cbocompra.Text = "";//pode usar o .Text = "" ou o .SelectedIndex = -1 para limpar o item seleccionado.
        }
        catch (SqlException sqle)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Falha ao efectuar a conexão. Erro: " + sqle);   
        }
    }
```

A seguir, no evento *`SelectedIndexChanged`*, não será necessário nova busca a base de dados. Os dados já estão no `DataSouce` da **ComboBox**. Para obter a linha seleccionada, usamos apenas a propriedade `SelectedItem` que é do tipo `DataRowView`. Com este objecto, podemos aceder cada célula da linha seleccionada, indicando o nome ou o índice da coluna:

```
    private void cbocompra_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        //verifica se foi seleccionado um item na lista
        if (cbocompra.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {

             //Podemos obter o linha seleccionada com a propriedade SeletedItem                 
             DataRowView drw = ((DataRowView)cbocompra.SelectedItem);
             txtautor1.Text =  drw["titulo"].ToString();
             txtedit1.Text =  drw["editora"].ToString();
             txtpreco.Text =  drw["preco"].ToString();
         }
         else
         {
             txtautor1.Text = "";
             txtedit1.Text = "";
             txtpreco.Text = "";
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Bom se eu entendi em uma Index da **comboBox** possui mais de uma informação: Autor, Edit, Preço.. 
 Se quiser retirar esse valores você deve obter o index selecionado pelo cliente/usuário e especificar no **SelectedIndex** para depois usar o **SelectedItem**, mas como você tem 3 informações você deve obter esse valor para uma string e depois usar o foreach para separar usando o Split.

Seu código poderia ficar mas ou menos assim:

```
string DadosSelecionados = null;
            MyCombo.SelectedIndex = 0; //index que foi selecionado, EX:0
            DadosSelecionados = MyCombo.SelectedItem.ToString();

                                       //0           //1           //2
            DadosSelecionados = "O mundo Increvel, Editora Nova, R$325,50";//digamos que foram esses os dados selecionados
            string[] Dados = DadosSelecionados.Split(',');
                                           //0 1 2 << 3
            string[] MyDados = new string[3];
            int i = 0;
            foreach(string s in Dados)
            {
                MyDados[i] = s.ToString();
                i++; //mesma coisa de i+=1! não confunda com ++i;
            }

            //seta os dados no seus textbox
            TXTNome.Text = MyDados[0].ToString();
            TXTEditora.Text = MyDados[1].ToString();
            TXTpreco.Text = MyDados[2].ToString();
```

Tem erros devido a ser feito na mão mesmo.. mas você só precisa entender o conceito.. 
 :)

Answer (score 3):

Suponho que sejam múltiplos itens, então é melhor trabalhar com uma `List` e para cada item criar um objeto.

Exemplo de classe para os itens:

```
private class Item
{
    public string Autor {get; set;}
    public string Editora {get; set;}
    public string Preco {get; set;}

    public Item(string Autor, string Editora, string Preco)
    {
        this.Autor = Autor;
        this.Editora = Editora;
        this.Preco = Preco;
    }
}
```

Crie a lista para os itens

```
List<Item> lista = new List<Item>();
```

Obtem-se os dados da string como o colega `Vyctor Junior` fez e coloca o item na lista:

```
string DadosSelecionados = "As Loucas Aventuras de James West, Editora Nova, R$325,50";
string[] itens = DadosSelecionados.Split(new string[] { ", "});
Item it = new Item(itens[0], itens[1], itens[2]);
lista.Add(it);
```

O ComboBox aceita enumerações, então basta passar a lista para a propriedade `DataSource`. Para ele saber o que será exibido de cada item da lista, escreve o nome da propriedade da classe ou struct `Item` na propriedade do ComboBox `DisplayMember`. Suponhamos que seja `Autor`:

```
cbocompra.DataSource = lista;
cbocompra.DisplayMember = "Autor";
```

No evento de quando o usuário muda o item a propriedade `SelectedItem` vai ter o item selecionado (em forma de object). Daí é só fazer um cast e preencher os TextBox.

```
Item item= (Item)cbocompra.SelectedItem;
txtautor1.Text = item.Autor;
txtedit1.Text = item.Editora;
txtpreco.Text = item.Preco;
```

Essa é a forma mais fácil que eu conheço pra isso.
Eu fiz a mão, então podem ter erros de sintaxe. Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 3):

Com o visual studio isso é feito automaticamente com ajuda do ADO.NET. Basta você criar um DataSource com os campos e as tabelas desejadas, e utilizando o "clicar e arrastar" você coloca o ComboBox da tabela e os TextBox das colunas dentro do seu Form.

Observe a imagem abaixo:

[image: Exemplo de DataSource no Visual Studio 2015]

Explicando:
Quando você cria uma instância da tabela é criado um DataSet para acessar a base de dados, um TableAdapter para a interface acessar os dados e um BindingSource para selecionar as linhas.

O BindingSource que faz o controle dos dados selecionados e visíveis, ou seja, quando você selecionar um item na instância (ComboBox) que referencia a tabela, o BindingSource vai trocar todos os conteúdos das instâncias referenciadas pelas colunas (TextBox).

Lembrando que é melhor criar a referencia da tabela (ComboBox) primeiro, pois assim os TextBox vão assimilar o DataAdapter e o BindingSource automaticamente, caso contrario serão criados vários DataAdapters e  BindingSources